# About linear optimization

Tags: linear-algebra

What does linear optimization mean?
 I nead a reference for the basic definitions and some examples.
and What are the applications of  linear optimization in linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

A mathematical optimisation problem is one in which some function is either maximised or minimised relative to a given set of alternatives. Please refer to the following [link](https://www.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/407/notes/section1.pdf) for further explanation. I also personally recommend you read [this](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/lewis.pdf).